# How to fix "The joined path () is located outside of the base path component ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-templates, django-inlinecss

I am trying to add CSS styling to my html email to be sent so I used `django-inlinecss 0.3.0` but I keep getting this error:

```
The joined path (C:\css\bootstrap.css) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\User\Desktop\static_root)
```

In my template I am using the following:

```
{% load inlinecss %}
{% inlinecss "/css/bootstrap.css" %}
TEXT
{% endinlinecss %}
```

After debugging I found that the reason is due to

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\static_root\\css\\bootstrap.css'
```

Here is the files structure:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

So, how should I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't solve that error but I actually found an alternative solution to inline CSS in HTML Templates. in case you are linking an external file then go copy it and paste it into style tags. That won't work just yet! after you have done that go to https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/ and paste the file with the css in the style tags and click convert, it'll inline the CSS for you! Gd luck, and have a good day!